# Creating two arrays, one 0-indexed and the other ID indexed, with references connecting the two

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Title is hard to get here, but essentially what I'm trying to do is take some data retrieved from my database, and insert portions of it into two arrays:

1. First array is a regular ordered array, so

   ```
   $list = [
     0 => ['id' => 'a', 'value' => 2],
     1 => ['id' => 'b', 'value' => 4],
     // etc  
   ];
   ```
2. And the second array will use the object's unique id as the keys for the array, so

   ```
   $map = [
     'a' => ['id' => 'a', 'value' => 2],
     'b' => ['id' => 'b', 'value' => 4],
     // etc  
   ];
   ```

However, I'd like the actual contents of `$list` and `$map` to be linked via reference, so if I change one, the other gets updated.

```
// update `a`'s value
$map['a']['value'] = 10;

// will echo "TRUE"
echo ($list[0]['value'] === 10 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
```

However, the code I'm using isn't working, and I can see why, but not sure what to do to fix it.

Here is some pseudocode of what is kind of happening in my script:

```
<?php

// Sample data
$query_result = [
    ['id' => 'a', 'other_data' => '...'],
    ['id' => 'b', 'other_data' => '...'],
    ['id' => 'c', 'other_data' => '...'],
    // etc
];

$list = [];
$map = [];

foreach ($query_result as $obj) {
    // Problem is here, $temp_obj gets reassigned, rather than a new variable being created
    $temp_obj = ['foreign_key' => $obj['id'], 'some_other_data' => 'abc', ];

    // Try to have object that is inserted be linked across the two arrays
    $list[] = &$temp_obj;
    $map[$obj['id']] = &$temp_obj;
}

// Both will just contain my 3 copies of the last item from the query,
// in this case, `['id' => 'c', 'other_data' => '...'],`
var_dump($list);
var_dump($map);
```

This is a very simplified version of what is going on but basically it is the same.

So, as I'm looping through my objects and adding them to two arrays, `$list` and `$map`, how can I add those objects so they are links to one another?

Comment: Well you just want to change those two lines: `$list[] = &$temp_obj; $map[$obj['id']] = &$temp_obj;` to: `$map[$obj['id']] = $temp_obj; $list[] = &$map[$obj['id']];`

Comment: I made an example - https://eval.in/594572

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking similarly with this later, but in the other way, so `$map['a'] = &$list[count($list) - 1];` and was having problems with that. Way easier to do `$list[] = &$map['a']` since I'll have the ID on hand.

Comment: @splash58 you should post the answer so OP can accept it and then it won't show up in unanswered and well-voted question searches.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `&` in your code like this:

```
$list[] = $temp_obj;  
$map[$obj['id']] = $temp_obj;
```